# using multiple war's to resolve multiple scala versions

Tags: java, scala, maven, tomcat, apache-kafka

I normally use scala `2.10.x`.
Due to some limitation of the components which i have no control over, I have to use `kafka` client version [0.7.2](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html) However this version of `kakfa` can be compiled only with scala ver 2.9.2 and does not work with scala 2.10.
note: I can't use the newer versions of kafka, its not working, i have no control over actual `kafka` version so i must use this client version.  **so i must use kafka client 0.7.2**

So I had multiple options:

1. Download sources of `0.7.2` kafka client and compile with scala `2.10` unfortunately too many changes in sources to perform.
2. Use `jarajar` and update `scala-library.jar` to have a prefix in packaging something like `scala.* -> scala.29.*`, Then update kafka client 0.7.2 to import classes from `scala.29.*` I tried that and also had problems here.
3. This is what i'm going to do now - create another `.war` in my tomcat web server, as tomcat will load different wars with different classloaders, I can send my kafka requests instead of from my original `war` to from my `war1` to `war2` and `war2` will be a simple web app which will hold a simple `kafka client 0.7.2`.

**My question** : Does option 3 sounds wise? I have some thoughts about its overhead, if I send `GET` requests to `localhost` just because I have multiple `wars` to resolve having multiple classloaders issues how good/bad is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up compiling kafka client 0.7.2 with scala 2.10, was not hard, everything works.